# Three on node.js with ColladaLoarder

Tags: node.js, three.js, collada

I know now how use JsonLoader in three.js for node.js.
But I have see, in the folder examples (three\examples\js\loaders) of node module an other loader whose is ColladaLoader.

I have try to execute this loader, but he isn't in the core folder of module.
I obtain an error: "ColladaLoader is not a function"

I have try to make a require to this file, but I obtain an error even I make a require to three module : "Three is not defined"

How can I use this ColladaLoader in node.js?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var THREE = require("three");

eval(fs.readFileSync("bower_components/three.js/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js")+"");
```

First you load three.js, ensure you set it to a var with the uppercase name "THREE". Then you load the ColladaLoader - feels quite dirty.
A more beautiful solution would encapsule ColladaLoader.js to a node module.

Comment: This helped me big time, I couldn't figure out any other way but I reworked this as a MonkeyPatch class and fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `"ColladaLoader is not a function"`, then you did not reference to the `ColladaLoader.js` file.

Make sure to add `<script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>` (or where ever your src is located) in your `<head>` or `<body>` somewhere before calling the `ColladaLoader()` function.

Comment: In Client side, I don't have problem, It's on the node.js server.I want load Collada object to control motion of all mesh in scene, and also detect collision for example.